# How to add a new machine to an already running solrCloud?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

So, I have two instance of solr node running along with a embedded zookeeper on a single machine using the link [Set up solrCloud](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/getting-started-with-solrcloud.html). Now I want to add a new machine to this cluster. I run `bin\solr start -cloud -s ./solr -h newMachineIP -p 9000 -z oldMachineIP:9983`. It shows successful startup, but when I create a new collection it gives me an error saying "Server refused connection at: http://newMachineIp:9000/solr"

Comment: Does the URL work in your browser? How about with curl / wget from the Solr server?

Comment: Browsers on both machine works, but the new machine browser displays an error "SolrCore Initialization Failures"

Comment: Is it possible to set up solrCloud with different machine using an embedded zookeeper?

Comment: Check the Solr log on the new machine - it'll show you why the core initialization failed. Embedded zookeepers should be able to talk to each other IIRC, but is _not_ recommended for anything other than experimentation.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to set up multiple machines in solrCloud using embedded zookeeper. Any help?

Comment: Yes its kind of POC only.

Comment: Check the log on the failing server. It should tell you why core initialization is failing.

Comment: So, in the logs: Unable to create core. No coreNodeName for CoreDescriptor[name=gettingstarted;instanceDir=C:\path\to\dir\solr-7.1.0\solr-7.1.0\server\solr\gettingstarted]

Answer (score 0):

just a guess but... does C:\path\to\di‌​r\solr-7.1.0\solr-7.‌​1.0\server\solr\gett‌​ingstarted contain any spaces? If so, install Solr into a path with no spaces, this has been an issue before in Windows, and it's possible it still is in some code paths. Solr on Windows get much less testing than on linux.

Comment: I can not find anything related to installing solrCloud on different physical machine on solr official website. Have you done it? How do you set it up?